# Проблема с деплоем проекта Node + Angular

Tags: angular

Что я делаю.

1. Загружаю файл с фронтендом написанным на Ангуляр в папку
   public_html на хостинге в файл менеджере.
2. Меняю .htaccess на это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Далее захожу на сайт и появляется белый экран
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это все происходит из за того что я удаляю proxy.config.json и добавляю в environment.prod.ts apiUrl: 'http://webmaster.az' но если оставить proxy и удалить apiUrl то все работает

Вот как выглядит роутинг
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что в консоли браузера? Там можно понять загружается ли ваше приложение, если да, то какие ошибки

Comment: Все исправил. Спасибо что отозвались